# What error does a service throw if it doesn't get a response from another service for a long time?

Tags: kubernetes, exception, timeoutexception

In the microservice project, what error does a service throw if it does not receive a response from another service, although that service is up and running?(etc TimeoutException)

(etc TimeoutException)

Comment: Something like a "timeout exception" would make sense, but it very heavily depends on the protocol, language, and library stack in use.  Can you [edit] the question to include more details?

Comment: (As a design point, I try to advise my coworkers to keep synchronous HTTP calls under 1 second latency at most and use asynchronous mechanisms like message queues for anything you think that will run longer, rather than trying to figure out what timeout various proxies and gateways will impose on you.)